# Memory allocation with looping in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have a List class for char arrays. And I want to push back N arrays from 'a' to 'a..a'.

```
char* x;
SList list;
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
    x = new char[i+1];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        x[j] = 'a';
    }
    x[i] = '\0';
    list.push_back(&x);
}
```

But every time, x has the same address. And in result, my List object contains N pointers to the same address.
Is there a way to push back these arrays in loop with correct memory allocation?

Before asking found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53012431/memory-allocation-using-for-loop), but it doesn't provide a cool solution for my problem.

Comment: Sorry for grammar errors.

Comment: No worry, if you spot a typo you can always [edit] your question ;)

Comment: `list.push_back(&x);` Shall we *guess* what the type of `list` is? We have no idea what an `SList` is, other than that it is *not* from the standard library. No matter, pushing the address of an automatic variable is a *tremendous* code smell that something is way off.

Comment: You're storing the address of `x`, not its value. Variables never move, so you always store the same address.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Ideally one which does not need input, e.g. with harcoded inits.

Comment: Try `list.push_back(x);` instead (possibly adapting `SList` definition)

Comment: If you want a "cool" solution then abandon all the manual memory management and custom classes; reinventing wheels not required: [something like this](https://ideone.com/zxPLP4).

Comment: I recognize my problem with SList class. New problem goes beyond this question

Answer (score 4):

In each iteration of the loop `x = new char[i+1];` returns a *different* address, which is stored in `x`. So the *value* of `x` changes in each iteration, yet, the *address* of `x` doesn't.

Did you mean

```
list.push_back(x);
```

to add the address of the newly allocated memory? Of course this would require you to change the type of `list` the a collection of `char *`.

---

It must be mentioned that dereferencing `&x` after `x` goes out of scope will lead to undefined behaviour, because `x` doesn't exist anymore. You fill `list` with dangling pointers.

---

Finally I'd like to mention that you could avoid the nasty manual memory management and simply use a `std::vector<std::string>`.

```
std::vector<std::string> list;

for (unsigned int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) {
    std::string newString(i, 'a'); // string with i times 'a'

    list.push_back(newString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found a pretty straightforward solution:

```
char** x = new char*[n];
SList sl;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    x[i] = new char[i+1];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        x[i][j] = 'a';
    }
    x[i][i] = '\0';
    sl.push_back(&x[i]);
}
```

With having N addresses to store pointers to arrays. I can just add their addresses to my list object

Comment: FYI, `&x[i]` is literally just `x+i`. And your `x` had better live at *least* as long as your `sl`, and properly cleanup when no longer used, or this is a recipe for a memory leak and/or dangling pointers still. I strongly suspect whatever SList is, requiring a pointer to pointer to char for its push_back is itself a code smell that needs more thought and investigation for that mystery class all on its own.

Comment: frankly, you found a workaround, not a solution. Depending what you want to store in `s1` you should be using `std::string` and/or `std::array` / `std::vector` instead of adding more `**`

Comment: that's true. I see this problem. Ty

Comment: SList is just a wrapper for Common singly linked list structure, that stores char**

Comment: Have you considered that perhaps a list that stores `char**` is *not* necessarily the ideal container for your task? E.g., rather than shoehorning in data compatible to the format of an arguably inappropriate container, try using a more appropriate container in the first place. With the right container and data types, C++ can make seemingly difficult problems surprisingly simpler if you just let it, as I had hoped my [previous example](https://ideone.com/zxPLP4) showed.